# Rails - Smarter way to do this join?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join

I have these models:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players_to_teams
  has_many :teams, through: :players_to_teams
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players_to_teams
  has_many :players, through: :players_to_teams
end

class PlayersToTeam < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :team
end
```

The team has the type of sport ("Football") and the player has the home state ("CA").

I want a list of the first names of every football player from California.

The SQL would look like

```
SELECT p.FirstName 
FROM players AS p
INNER JOIN players_to_teams AS ptt
ON p.id = ptt.player_id 
INNER JOIN teams AS t 
ON t.id = ptt.team_id 
WHERE t.sport_name = "Football" AND p.home_state = "CA"
```

The only thing I can think is to get all the football players `fb_players = Sport.find_all_by_sport_nane("Football")`, then iterate over all of `fb_players.players` and see who is from California, but that just feels way slower than a single SQL statement.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

```
Player.select("firstName").joins(:teams).where(:"teams.sport_name" => "Football", :home_state => "CA").map(&:firstName)
```

---

To answer your comment:

Doing `.map(&:firstName)` is like doing `.map{ |player| player.firstName }`.
Basically, the `&` is transforming a Proc into a block to pass to the `map` method. But `:firstName` is not a block?! Right. But ruby automatically calls `to_proc` method on the symbol.

The `to_proc` method is defined like that:

```
def to_proc
    proc { |obj, *args| obj.send(self, *args) }
end
```

Comment: This looks close, but the `sport_name` is on `teams`.  This query tries `players.sport_name`. Is there a way to change that?

Comment: I edited my answer, I think this should work. I thought that if there was no ambiguity in the column names, rails was handling this stuff. Apparently not.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Can you explain what the `map(&:firstName)` does? Specifically, the `&` part?

Comment: I answered your question in my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try has_and_belongs_to_many

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teams, :join_table = "players_to_teams"
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :players, :join_table = "players_to_teams"
end
```

http://jonathanhui.com/ruby-rails-3-model-many-many-association